# Run Sql Query (DELETE) from Eclipse

Tags: java, sql

I try to run sql query to delete specific record from my database in SQL SERVER 2008.
I'm using this command:

```
 st.executeUpdate("delete  from  TblMachine Where TblUsers=35");
```

and its works. but I want that the UserID(35) will be variable that I have. 
how can I do that?

thanks!!

Comment: Can you please elaborate "UserID(35) will be variable". What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Viktor: I think he means, it could also be `68` or `123` or any other number.

Answer (score 5):

Use Prepared Statement:
**http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html**

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("delete  from  TblMachine Where TblUsers=?");
pstmt.setInt(1, 35);
```

Instead of 35 in **pstmt.setInt()** you can have: **pstmt.setInt(1, yourVariable);**

Comment: Hi, Thanks!
after I used:  pstmt.setInt(1, 35);
It should delete the record? or should I run another command?

Comment: @user2097810: `pstmt.execute();`